# How to reference java.time.LocalDate in hbm file?

Tags: hibernate, java-8, hibernate-mapping, java-time

How to reference `java.time.LocalDate` type in a `*hbm.xml` file? I tried `type="localdate"` and it didn't work. Unfortunatelly it is not allowed to use annotations in this project to map entities.

The question [How to persist LocalDate into Hibernate as a Date type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178499) does not answer my question because when I use `type="date"` hibernate maps it to `java.util.Date` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to persist LocalDate into Hibernate as a Date type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178499/how-to-persist-localdate-into-hibernate-as-a-date-type)

Comment: No, it does not. When I use `type="date"` hibernate maps it to `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs and if you are using [5.2](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-provided) you should able to map using `LocalDate` or `java.time.LocalDate`

```
<property name="date" column="tb_date" type="LocalDate" />
```

Comment: It is curious that for `LocalDate` hibernate demands it to be declared case-sentively, althought this is not required for `date`.